TeamCity REST API versioned settings status at revision
There is a versioned setting enabled for some root project and they are located in a separate vcs-root (let's say vs-vcs). It is expected that it will be possible to run builds within this root project with settings of a given revision.
There is a service that generates versioned settings and pushes them to vs-vcs. I want to check if versioned settings at a given revision are valid, but couldn't find any corresponding TeamCity REST API requests. Is there any?
